# gitlab kubernernetes integration: configuring the installed runner

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, cicd, gitlab-ci-runner

I connected my existing kubernetes cluster to gitlab using the gitlab integration in myproject/operations/kubernetes on the left tab pane in the gitlab gui.

After having installed helm + gitlab runner from the gitlab GUI applications, the new gitlab runner is visible in the project runners.

What I don't understand from the gitlab documentation is how do you modify  the new runner's configuration. You cannot use the gitlab-runner cli, like for a non-kubernetes runner, because the runner in running in a pod, not on the host machine, right?

I am not sure which part of the runner doc applies to my case. What to use if I wanted to make the runner use another executor or build from another image ? (default image of the pod is ubuntu 16 for me).

If you have already installed and configured a runner installed this way, from the GUI, please tell me how. Thank you.

Gitlab 12.9.2 hosted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Installing kubernetes integration on gitlab**

In Admin Area -> Overview -> Runners, the instructions they give are:

1. Install GitLab Runner
2. Specify the following URL during the Runner setup: `https://<your gitlab hostname>/`
3. Use the following registration token during setup: `<insert-token-here>`
4. Start the Runner!

*I'm on version 13.13.0 but I don't remember the instructions changing from version 12.x.x.*

**Project specific runners**

As for your question regarding configuration, I'm a little bit confused if you're looking for something beyond those instructions. If you want to set up a runner specific to a project, you can go to a project then navigate to Settings -> CI/CD -> Runners -> Specific Runners. There, there are more instructions on setting up project-specific runners.

**Further configuring the runner**

**EDIT**: The executor entirely depends on how the runner itself is installed. If it's installed on a kubernetes cluster, then it *must* be the kubernetes executor. That will affect your pipeline. I think you can create another one if you install another one with the runner chart. You can also use Helm Tiller.

Comment: Thanks, this I already did. What I don't understand it how to further configure the runner, e.g. change its executor (docker, shell, virtualbox...) or change the image it uses (default is ubuntu 16)

Comment: also, gitlab created one runner. what if I wanted a second one ? am I missing something in the GUI?

Comment: Oh, I think the executor entirely depends on how the runner itself is installed. If it's installed on a kubernetes cluster, then it _must_ be the kubernetes executor. That will affect your pipeline. I think you can totally create another one if you install another one with the runner chart. You can also use Helm Tiller.

Comment: thanks I will try configuring the runner with chart or helm then ! add your comment to the answer so I can accept it

Comment: I added my comment with a few edits.

Comment: One thing I might add to your question are the comments you sent to me about the runner executor.

Comment: I made the question clearer !